# why does :empty return link and image?

Tags: html, css

why does `:empty` returns link and image?

I don't see any point in returning image and link by :empty selector as only attributes of these tags matter.

[this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#empty-pseudo) says
The :empty pseudo-class represents an element that has no children at all.

Is this the way defined in latest standard?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @Adrift What code..? `<img><link>`...? There's no need for code in this question.

Comment: Well what do you mean by "why does :empty returns link and image"?

Comment: Images and `<link>` elements don't have children, so why shouldn't they match the selector?

Comment: :empty should be applicable for elements for which definition of child is valid.

Comment: The definition of child is valid even for elements that can't have children.

Comment: "The :empty pseudo-class represents any element that has no children at all. Only element nodes and text (including whitespace) are considered. Comments or processing instructions do not affect whether an element is considered empty or not."

Answer (score 0):

**If** the :empty pseudo-class represents an element that has no children at all **and** the `:empty` selector does not represent a particular `img` element, **then** that particular `img` element has at least one child element.

That's simple deductive reasoning.

Adding exceptions for elements that are always empty according to the HTML standard would make that rule more complicated.

Comment: Thanks..What kind of complication? We have attribute and element support table defined with exceptions right? only global attributes are valid for all elements and for others we always have to look into that relation table. Same could have done here also.

Answer (score 0):

`:empty` does, as you say, select all the elements without any children (actually all those without any content).

I think you are asking "Why the need of selecting `<link>` and `<image>`".

Well, first of all, `:empty` is just a selector that selects by a certain rule. Wouldn't it be more confusing, if `:empty` left out some elements and showed only some? It would be inconsistent and hard to work with with build-in exceptions.

(With that said, I still do follow your questioning of why the `<link>` element is also selected. The above reasoning applies still in some way, but clearly `<link>` is never the intended selection...)